# List filter doesn't work on keyup, ignores some list items

Tags: jquery

I found this great list filtering jQuery script and implemented to my simple `ol` `li` list. When you type something on the search, it searches for the typed letter from the `li` items and hides the rest of the `lis`. Works perfect!

But, I implemented the same script to a more complicated `list`. The only differece is the HTML, I have extra `divs` inside my `li` where as the other one doesn't. When I search for something on the new `list` it doenst work properly. When I delete the search term, it should `slideDown` all the original `li` items but it doenst. Can you guys pleasae have a look at the fiddle below and tell me what Im doing wrong?

Working simple list [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBCLv/1/)
Not properly working list [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vesa9/1/)

I have a feeling its the script below

```
$(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
$(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
```

I tried few different ways, none of them worked.!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please tell me if I need to clarify more. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.
    http://jsfiddle.net/mpt8T/

```
$(list).find('li').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).text().indexOf(filter) >= 0 )
        $(this).slideDown();
    else
        $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: I put in some real data, then it doesn't work. Can you check `http://jsfiddle.net/tpGXm/1/`? I just updated the HTML with my real data, now it doesnt work.

Comment: if you search `Nissan` or `Atlast`, everything slidesUp.

Comment: Yes its because your text contains the text "Nissan 180SX MA 1989/01 – 1999/12". If you search for Nissan i works, but if you search for nissan it dont. The search is case sensitive.

Comment: I have updated the code. You had a onclick on the input, maybe thats why it fails for you? http://jsfiddle.net/mpt8T/